# django error: cart.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: updateBtns[i].addEventListner is not a function at cart.js:4

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django

I have never worked with js until now and i keep getting this error

```
cart.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: updateBtns[i].addEventListner is not a function
     at cart.js:4
```

I have searched it and none of the answers that i used helped.

cart.js

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (var i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListner('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.products
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId: ', productId, 'action: ', action)
    })
}
```

store.html

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <form method="GET" action=".">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn2'>Search</button>
                </div>
              <div class="column">
                  <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ product.imageURL }}">
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h6><strong>{{ product.name }}</strong></h6>
                <hr>

                <button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">View</a>
                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>R{{ product.price|floatformat:2 }}</strong></h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

part of store.html

```
<button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

i am using python django and trying to make a cart system for my ecom store

Comment: Its a typo; 'addEventListner' should be 'addEventListener'

Comment: thanks, i did not see that